# Crash in reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: Attempt to delete row containing first responder that refused to resign

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, ipad

I'm stuck on this error. First the code is in swift, not objective C. I am using a UITableView where the the cells can be expanded with additional subviews when selected. When I select a cell, it expands. When I select another cell, the first cell contracts and the new selected cell expands. This is all fine. The code uses this command:

```
super.viewTable!.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(cellsToUpdate, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
```

The problem is that one of the subviews in the expanded cell can pop up a UIAlertController when pressed. If I pop up this UIAlertController and cancel it so it goes away, then when I press any other cell in my table, the app crashes with this error:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:], 
/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44.2/UITableView.m:2924
2015-10-05 15:59:32.276 MyAppName[46504:1975727] *** Terminating app due 
to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempt 
to delete row containing first responder that refused to resign'
```

In other words, everything works fine unless I pop up an alert in the expanded cell. Unfortunately I HAVE TO pop up the alert in the expanded cell to make the program useful. So I need to fix this issue and have no idea how. How can I force whatever is holding on to first responder status in the expanded cell give it up? How can I even see what that first responder is? I have tried to call endEditing(true) and similar sorts of things. I do not have a UITextView as a subview anywhere, so that isn't the problem. Any ideas how to fix this?

I'm open to ideas how toI tried calling reloadData() before the call to reloadRowsAtIndexPaths. Nothing works so far.

UPDATE: Well guess what. There may be a bug in UIAlertController, because when I replace all my UIAlertController code with UIAlertView, everything now works fine, no crashes. Somehow UIAlertController screws up some first responder somewhere so that it now refuses to release first responder status. UIAlertView is a bit more annoying to set up, with UIALertViewDelegate and such, but at least it works without crashing.

But this still begs the question, what could be going wrong in UIAlertController?

Comment: Have you tried `self.view.endEditing(true)`?

Comment: Yes I tried that. Didn't help.

Comment: @CharlesA. yeah its working thank you! 
put this in viewDidLayoutSubviews